# Reading multiindex from Excel - how do I reset index without losing leading zeroes?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, multi-index

As the title states, `df.reset_index()` is currently dropping leading zeroes in several of my columns because the columns are converted to int64. The Excel-files consists of product and business-codes, showing which codes belong in different aggregates. Different codes may have a varying number of leading zeroes, and the codes themselves has a varying number if digits, so `.zfill()` doesn't quite cut it. I have a quick-fix at hand, modifying the data, but I would like to learn how to circumnavigate such issues in the future.

This is how I currently read the files within a loop:

```
df = pd.read_excel("mappingOfAggregates.xlsx", index_col=[0,1,2,3], dtype=str)
```

I have also used `df = df.astype('object')` after each file has been read, but it does not seem to affect the final result when I use `df.reset_index()`.

Chat GPT suggests that I reset index and then use `.astype('object')` on each column - which works as well as one would expect.

Any pointers in the right direction is received with thanks.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, you can specify your columns' dtypes as string, then set these columns as index which keeps their values as-is.

Comment: @FurkanTektas The issue is the other way around. The Excel-sheet is structured as a multiindex, and I therefore have read it using the argument "index_col=[0,1,2,3]". When the columns are set as indexes, I am unable to change their type - at least as far as I know.

Comment: Okay then, you can still specify the dtype of the index column as string. So assuming column names are A,B,C,D, you should be able to retain the values as they are:

pd.read_excel("mappingOfAggregates.xlsx", index_col=[0,1,2,3], dtypes={'A':pd.StringDtype(), 'B':pd.StringDtype(), 'C': pd.StringDtype(), 'D':pd.StringDtype()})

Comment: @FurkanTektas Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm! If you put this as your answer, I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin, glad that it worked. Posting as an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retain the indexes with `index_col` argument but to keep leading zeros you need to specify the type of the column as string not a numeric value.

Assuming you have columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` as the index, you can achieve that by providing a dictionary with each column name corresponds to a `str`, `'str'` or `pd.StringDtype()` as follows:

```py
pd.read_excel(
    "mappingOfAggregates.xlsx",
    index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3],
    dtypes={
        "A": pd.StringDtype(),
        "B": pd.StringDtype(),
        "C": pd.StringDtype(),
        "D": pd.StringDtype(),
    },
)
```